# How to fill gaps in line from missing values, using ggplot geom_path

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to plot a depth/salinity graph, and need the observations connected in the order they appear, so I am using geom_path. However when I use geom_path, there are gaps in the data from missing values in the dataframe. I'm sure it's a simple fix, but I cannot seem to find out how to fix it.

This is my code, and the output is shown in the image

[image]

```
sal3 <- 
  ggplot(data = CTD3, mapping = aes(x=SALINITY_BOTTLE, y=`Pressure [dB]`)) + geom_point() + geom_path()
```

I tried to use na.rm=FALSE, but it did nothing. I also tried to use geom_line, but then the line is not in the order I need it to be (it plots in the order of x-values).

Comment: Hi, it sounds like a missing data issue, do you have `SALINITY_BOTTLE` values that don't have a matching pressure value?

It would be easier to troubleshoot if you could share your data with something like a `dput(CTD3)` Or see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) for suggestions to make a reproducible example.

Are there any warnings like: Removed N rows containing missing values (geom_point())?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [ggplot doc](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_path.html?q=connect#missing-value-handling) you need to set na.rm=TRUE, it will remove the missing values silently without breaking the line in the middle.